# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpha_vantage'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, alpha-vantage

```
import pandas as pd
from aplha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import time
api_key = '*************'

ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='MSFT', interval = '1min', output_size = 'full')
print(data)
```

When I try to pull the data into the terminal it gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError` on `alpha_vantage` even though I had installed it using terminal.

I'm using `pycharm` and python 3.9

Comment: You might have installed it using the terminal but WHERE did you install it?  Are you using a virtual env?  Are you using the system install?  You're most likely not running the version of python that you think you are

Comment: @sedavidw I'm using a virtual environment

Comment: And are you sure that the virtual env that you installed to is the same one you're running in PyCharm?  PyCharm lets you select your interpreter and you can select your virtual env, that might be a good place to start looking.  To be clear there's nothing wrong with your code this is simply a case of python not knowing where the `alpha_vantage` module is

Comment: Just to rule it out - do you have a typo in your code?  You have alpha spelled as aplha in the from statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it has a virtual environment and you are installing it outside.

If I create a project in pycharm, this step will work.

1. Click the interpreter in the bottom right corner of the project and select 'Interpreter Settings'
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlCIC.png)
2. click in icon more
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOOp5.png)
3. Write the name of the library and click in install package
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2a4I.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can enter virtual env then excute pip list to check if installed

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what interpreter pycharm is using. Do this:

1. Open Pycharm
2. Hit "file" and look for "settings" or "other settings"
3. Click then then look for something with "preferences"
4. Now look for "project interpreter"

You now you can do one of two things

1. Add the package yourself to the interpreter

   a. There is a little plus button at the bottom you can hit, and add
   "alpha-vantage"
2. Make the pycharm interpreter the same as your command line
   interpreter (the thing you did `pip install alpha-vantage` on)

   b. You can find out what interpreter you're using with `which python` on the command line, and just make them the same.